# Confusing dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a VBA script that opens up a bunch of CSV files, and compiles them into one summary report.

However, I'm having a problem where it reads in UK style dates (dd/mm/yyyy), then interprets them as US-style dates when it makes the copy, before display them as UK-style dates again!

So 4th of July in original sheet becomes 7th of April in the summary sheet - verified by changing cell format to display month name.

This is odd, as when you open up the CSV file in Excel, it correctly interprets the UK style date.

Copy is made using code like this

```
SummarySheet.Cells(Y,X).value = CSVSheet.Cells(W,Z).value
```

What is going on here?

Comment: VBA uses the US style by default while Excel does look at your language settings. I'm afraid you are stuck with parsing the date correctly yourself. You could also try using ADO to get data from the CSV file but that may be taking it a bit too far.

Comment: @Tom internally in Excel are dates not handled as some form of number, like Unix time or similar? Is there no way of just copying this (formatting agnostic) number?

Comment: When opening the CSV file Excel tends to try to convert the columns to a format that it knows, so in this case a date. This date is actually a number (format the cell as a number instead of a date and you will see that) The converting of the supplied text is handled differently when Excel opens the CSV file compared to opening the file using VBA. It is not too difficult to parse the text value yourself though (just a bit tedious)

Comment: So calling `Workbooks.Open("Csvfile.csv")` is not the same as me going FIle->Open->"Csvfile.csv"... Once again, all is made unclear by MS and VB

Comment: One method would be to `Import` the data and use the text import wizard to properly parse the dates, setting the `TextFileColumnDataType` to `xlDMYFormat`.  I would suggest using the macro recorder to see what it might look like  `Data Ribbon / Get External Data Tab / From Text` and then modifying that routine to suit.

Comment: A better method might be to use the OpenText method.  This, also, will allow you to specify how to parse the date column

Comment: Is the file being opened manually, or by the code?

Comment: @MacroMan - by the code, in fact, many CSVs from one folder are being opened by the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the code as to how you are opening your CSV files -- that is the critical area. The dates need to be parsed properly BEFORE being entered on the worksheet.  The following code will selects and then opens a file that has UK style dates in a single column, and properly parse them.  You will need to adapt it to your particular requirements.

The `FieldInfo` argument is what does the work.  The formatting of the Excel worksheet is "for show" so you can see an unambiguous date.

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenUKcsv()
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet

sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True, other:=False, _
                    fieldinfo:=Array(1, 4)

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = ActiveSheet

With WS.Columns(1)
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks.OpenText` as opposed to `Workbooks.Open` seems to do the job - althogh the fieldinfo parameter would help avoid confusion.

Comment: @CMaster  Yes, if you omit FieldInfo, it will parse according to your Windows Regional Settings.  So including it enables the dates to be properly parsed, even if someone changes those settings on their machine.  In addition,  I would suggest you specify **all** the delimiters, as those may get carried over from prior usage of the `Data / Text to Columns` wizard. For my sample, I only needed to specify `other:=false`, but for a realtime application, I would specify everything except `comma` as being false; and consider the other optional arguments also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.Text` (text displayed in Excel cell) or `.Value2` (value without formatting) instead of `.Value` (value with formatting).

But I strongly suggest that you set the format of the cells that you use to what you expect to have at the end with `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`

Or you could use `CDate` function :

```
SummarySheet.Cells(Y,X).value = CDate(CSVSheet.Cells(W,Z).value)
```

Or use an UDF with `DateSerial` :

```
Sub test_CMaster()
MsgBox ParseDate("4/7/15") & vbCrLf & CDate("4/7/15")
End Sub

Function ParseDate(ByVal DateInCell As String, Optional Separator As String = "/") As Date
Dim D() As String
D = Split(DateInCell, Separator)
    ParseDate = DateSerial(D(UBound(D)), D(1), D(0))
End Function
```

Comment: Value2  gives the exact same result (transposes the day and month). As does .text

Comment: Ok, and what about `CDate`?

Comment: Or you can try the custom function `ParseDate` with `DateSerial`! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Workbooks.OpenText()` method instead and set the `Local` flag to `True`

```
Set csvWB = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=myCSVfile, Local:=True)
```

[Here is the MSDN article on this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837097.aspx) which says for the `Local` setting:

> Specify **True** if regional settings of the machine should be used for separators, numbers and data formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert the CSV files to show dates as numbers, ie. 10th Nov 15 will show as 42318. Or add a separate column where B1 is `=DATEVALUE(A1)` and work with that.

When you create the summary report, import the numbers and convert them to date using `CDate` and `Format`. Something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Range("A2:A4").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Range("A2").Value = Format(CDate(Range("A1").Value), "dd.mm.yyyy")
    Range("A3").Value = Format(CDate(Range("A1").Value), "mm.dd.yyyy")
    Range("A4").Value = Format(CDate(Range("A1").Value), "Long Date")
End Sub
```

EDIT:

For better formatting (no need for `NumberFormat`, I think it will use your regional settings right away) and auto-setting the cell format to date-type, use this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sDate As Date
    sDate = CDate(Range("A1").Value)
    Range("A2").Value = DateSerial(Year(sDate), Month(sDate), Day(sDate))
End Sub
```

Result:
[image: Excel VBA date display]

References:
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdate.php